# How adding ImageSpan in jetpack compose Text

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, spannablestring, spannable, android-jetpack-compose-text

As we know, [AnnotatedString](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString) in JetpackCompose has provided some API of [Android's SpannedString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannedString).

but I didn't find any way/workaround to inline [ImageSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/style/ImageSpan) to a Text (except using AndroidView)

Comment: For now, they [don't have](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149716568) any plan to support it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Putting images inside text can be done using `AnnotatedString` and `inlineContent` parameter of `Text` Composable.

- Inside `buildAnnotatedString { ... }` we need to define some **id** for our inline content using `appendInlineContent(id = ...)`
- Then in `Text` Composable in `inlineContent` parameter  we provide a map matching this **id** to `InlineTextContent()` object.

You can basically put any content there as long as you can define its size up-front in `Placeholder`.

Here is how it looks with an `Image` put in the middle of the text:
[image]

```
val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
    append("This is text ")
    appendInlineContent(id = "imageId")
    append(" with a call icon")
}
val inlineContentMap = mapOf(
    "imageId" to InlineTextContent(
        Placeholder(20.sp, 20.sp, PlaceholderVerticalAlign.TextCenter)
    ) {
        Image(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Call,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentDescription = ""
        )
    }
)

Text(annotatedString, inlineContent = inlineContentMap)
```

Comment: There's an interesting caveat here, that you have to know the size of the content up-front. In my case, I can only figure it out by spending the time to render the image up-front, which kind of sucks. I wonder what happens if I just put the wrong size in...

Comment: you should put `inlineContentMap`  in a remember

Comment: @mr.icetea `remember` doesn't allow while message is being appended using `stringResource(resId)`.