# How do I wrap text around an image or a composable?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, jetbrains-compose

How do I wrap text around an image or a composable?
Something similar to [FlowTextView](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView) in Jetpack Compose.

I am wondering if there is a possibility to leave a certain space free so that if the text is too long it breaks a line and writing continues underneath the free space completely normally without the space being overwritten.

**I have this:**

[image]

**I want to do this:**

[image]

I try to do this with compose for desktop but should be the same as with android jetpack compose.
I do not know if it is, for now, possible but I can't find a way to manipulate the `Text` composable.
Found [PlaceHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/Placeholder) and [TextLayoutInput](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextLayoutInput) but i don't know how to use it. Maybe impossible.

Comment: Have edited the question with a link to FlowTextView. You can use this library and android view in compose to achieve what you want in android. But not sure how it can be done in desktop, hence leaving a comment and not an answer.

Comment: https://youtu.be/R430EqT-IaQ this video explains it very well

Comment: @RaBaKa78 - Video is unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting images inside text can be done using AnnotatedString and inlineContent parameter of Text Composable.

[How adding ImageSpan in jetpack compose Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70067723/how-adding-imagespan-in-jetpack-compose-text)

Comment: have not test it yet, but good to know. thanks

Comment: The link you provided covers something (an image) flowing together with the text. But the original question is about the "something" being fixed at the top-righthand corner. That's indeed something I haven't found a solution yet except Lucas Perretta's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of an old question but in Compose you can use the **[Text Flow](https://github.com/oleksandrbalan/textflow)** dependency. It has support for wrapping text around any composable and it also allows for fun animations!