# Android Jetpack Compose text that starts next to the image and continues below it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How can I make a design like the image with Jetpack Compose? I searched a lot, but I couldn't get any answer similar to the structure I wanted.

[image]

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73819143/17787605

Comment: Thanks for your reply @bylazy No matter how small I enlarge the image, it does not exceed the size of the text. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Dont't think it's possible with out-of-box Compose components. Here is some link from another similar question: https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView

Comment: How about https://github.com/oleksandrbalan/textflow ?

Comment: @Alejandra You are super :) Thank you very much, here is the answer I was looking for :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try out Romain's newest library

```
Composable widget for Jetpack Compose that allows to flow text around arbitrary shapes over multiple columns.
```

to achieve this and much more: https://github.com/romainguy/combo-breaker

Answer (score 0):

How about using a simple Text only, but inside a Box where we can clip the size of the image using modifier!!

```
Box {
  Image(modifier = modifier.clicp(RoundedCornerShape(...)))
  Text(...)
}
```

`modifier.clip(...)` is something which can do the trick.

Comment: I don't think this will provide the desired result. `Box` usually places composables above another, not around other composable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Images inside text using AnnotatedString and inLineContent parameter of `Text` Composable
like [How adding ImageSpan in jetpack compose Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70067723/how-adding-imagespan-in-jetpack-compose-text)

or you can use `Box` Composable and Clip your image using `Modifier.clip(Shape)`